# Is google voice number is SMS-capable

Tags: sms, twilio, phone-number, voice

Is google voice number is SMS-capable? I am getting the following error from rails app:

> A Twilio::REST::RequestError occurred in sms#dispatcher_api:    The From phone number +14242752338 is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account.   twilio-ruby (3.9.0) lib/twilio-ruby/rest/client.rb:226:in 'connect_and_send'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio only supports the `From` being a number you lease from them.

So the error you're getting is Twilio telling you they won't allow that number to be used as the sender, not that the number isn't capable of receiving SMS messages.

That's what is meant by (emphases added):

> a valid, SMS-capable **inbound phone number** or short code **for your account**